# Given the angle between planes $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ is equal to the angle between...

Tags: plane-geometry

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this question but i keep coming to a hexic equation rather than a quartic equation.

the three planes: 
$$\pi_1: ax+2y+z=3$$
$$\pi_2: x+ay+z=4$$
$$\pi_3: x+y+az=5$$

Given the angle between planes $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ is equal to the angle between $\pi_2$ and $\pi_3$, show that $a$ must statisfy the quartic equation
$$5a^4+2a^3-2a^2-8a-3=0$$

Comment: If you’d like someone to point out where you’re going wrong, then you should show your work.

Answer (score 0):

Given the planes

$$
\pi_k \to \left<p-p_k,\vec n_k\right> = 0
$$

with $p = (x,y,z)$

if

$$
\frac{\left< \vec n_1,\vec n_2\right> ^2}{||\vec n_1||^2||\vec n_2||^2} = \frac{\left< \vec n_2,\vec n_3\right> ^2}{||\vec n_2||^2||\vec n_3||^2} 
$$

then

$$
5a^4+2a^3-2a^2-8a-3 = 0
$$

here $\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>$ represents the scalar product of two vectors

Comment: what does the first line mean? I'm not very good with notation

Comment: @H.Linkhorn For the first plane we have $\vec n_1 = (a,2,1)$ and $p_1 = (0,0,3)$